# I can't perform "click()" to skip a screen

Tags: android, click, android-espresso, ui-testing

Espresso recorder wrote me the next code:

```
ViewInteraction appCompatTextView2 = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.skipBtnTextView_BirthdayActivity), withText("Skip this step"), childAtPosition(allOf(withId(R.id.skipLayout_BirthdayActivity), childAtPosition(withClassName(is("android.widget.LinearLayout")),4)),1),isDisplayed()));
appCompatTextView2.perform(click());
```

It does not work after running. I replaced it with:

```
onView(withId(R.id.skipBtnTextView_BirthdayActivity)).check(matches(withText("Skip this step")));
onView(withId(R.id.skipBtnTextView_BirthdayActivity)).perform(click());
```

But it fails too.

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing
'single click - At Coordinates: 539, 1359 and precision: 16, 16' on
view 'with id: com.ingenio.keen:id/skipBtnTextView_BirthdayActivity'.
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: could you explain more? you want skip a screen to go to another activity or what?

Comment: @docbigolo yes, exactly. Previously, I register a new user, navigate to screen with birthday date choosing and want to skip it in order to get to the  Home screen... but on step with clicking on "Skip this step" button I get a fail. Don't know, there is the problem... earlier I didn't have a stuck on such an easy deal....

Answer (score -1):

first of all you should define your button/textView etc like this:

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

you should give an id to your button in your layout.xml

then you should write a setOnClickListener:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


          Intent intent=new Intent(YourActivity.this,DestanationActivity.class);
          startactivity(intent);//you will go to home screen activity with this 

        }
    });
```